# Returning the Last Record in a Range when the query exceeds the range

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a table

```
{ID, Code, OffSet, Amount},
{1, 1, 1, .30}
{2, 1, 2, .45}
{3, 1, 3, .50}
{4, 2, 1, .26}
```

If I know the exact offset I can query easily enough. But what if the offset is not included in the table? How can I get a query to return the last valid record for a given code from with a join?

For example, if my query contained code = 1 and offset = 4, it should return the Amount of .50 from Record with ID 3

```
SELECT T1.Account, T2.Amount
  FROM Table1 T1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 on T2.Code = T1.Code and T2.Offset = 4  --?? What goes here??
 WHERE T1.Account = 'ABCD'
```

I am using MSSQL 2008 R2.

Thanks.

Comment: The original post contains a table and a hypothetical query, though not in SELECT form.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get a query to return the last valid record for a given code?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTbl WHERE Code = 1 AND OffSet <= 4 ORDER BY OffSet DESC
```

Assuming the `ID` field is auto-increment.

Comment: That is the last physical record in the table. I am looking for the last valid record in the range given a code of 1 and an offset outside the range.

Comment: I think that OP wants to find first row matching `code` parameter and having `offset` less or equal to `offset` parameter, ordered descendingly by offset.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Does that do it for you?

Comment: The Select statement works well. I neglected to include the fact that this part of the query is a join statement. I don't think TOP 1 is valid syntax in a join.

Comment: @LinksUp You can take `TOP 1` out and just use the first record in the record set.

Comment: As with most examples, they are small to demo the problem or question. The reality is that this query is just a part of a larger query with other joins. Having it return a set of records will add to the other joins to create an n*m result set. Thus I need a way to only return 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

Here your Id is unique and assume when new record is insert it is more than existing id..

so, you can easily fetch that record using  top 1 record and order by id desc 
I am using your query to resolve that

```
SELECT T1.Account, T2.Amount
  FROM Table1 T1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 on T2.Code = T1.Code and T2.Offset = 4  
 WHERE T1.Account = 'ABCD' order by T1.Id desc Limit 1
```

Note : top is use in sql server and limit is use in mysql